# Adding zero to an int variable results in weird number

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with what should be simple additon in Javascript.

Take a look at this firebug output:

[image: Firebug output screenie]

What I'm making is a 2D tile map in canvas, and for objects in the map that are greater than one tile in size, they have their width and height set to negative numbers, to tell me how many tiles offset in x/y they are to get to the tile with the relevant data.

This works fine for all cases, except when adding zero to a number.  This results in strange numbers.

In the image above, there are two click events fired, each starting with "clicking on X x Y" and ending with "modified x/y into X Y".  As you can see, clicking on a tile with a -3 for the Y offset works fine, but clicking on a tile with 0 for the Y offset results in 247!???  I've been going over and over this without getting any closer to an answer.  All data seems fine, right up to the point when I try and add 0 to the variable y.  If that wasn't weird enough, adding zero to the x variable works fine!

Here's the snippet of code that outputs the debug messages and causes the error.  x and y are parameters to a function call, and cityMap is a global 3D array.

```
if (cityMap[x][y]['typeID']<0)
{
    // get deffered tile pos
    console.debug("Offset x = "+cityMap[x][y]['width']);
    console.debug("Offset y = "+cityMap[x][y]['height']);  
    x += parseInt(cityMap[x][y]['width'], 10);
    y += parseInt(cityMap[x][y]['height'], 10);
    console.debug("modified x/y into x:"+x+" y:"+y);
}
```

I'm completely lost for ideas here.  Does anyone know what else I can try to stop Javascript doing this?

Comment: Is it possible that y has been modified somewhere else  ? add a debug message to print the value of y before the `+=` instruction to be sure...

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/N2WQr/

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that Javascript is doing something wrong here. Have you tried stepping through the function in Firebug and watching the variables involved?

Comment: Maybe this variable is stored as a string? Can you try "casting" the Variable to an integer, "247" looks like 2^8 - 10 (i dunno where the -10 is from, but maybe from the X?... its JS :)) So try multiplying by 1: y = y*1 + ..., or use a parseint function.

Comment: Answer:
Oh dear, it was so simple, and I feel so stupid.. The problem is these two lines:

x += parseInt(cityMap[x][y]['width'], 10);
y += parseInt(cityMap[x][y]['height'], 10);

At the time the second line is called, x has been modified by the first line to a different value, causing the second line to read from a different array element. D'oh! Time to google for a 50ft tall gif of a facepalm...

(had to answer in a reply because apparently newbies can't answer their own question within 8 hours of posting.  What a strange rule)

Answer (score 0):

+1 For all those developers that solve their own questions! I got this one, but I read then your comment so the answer is yours and I'm not writing it down.